# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebaseui is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebaseui

The website does not display anything. It gives the error: firebaseui not defined.
I am running my code in eclipse, on my localhost web server. The error is displayed in "app.js" file of a sample web application I took from github.  The output must show sign-in widgets.

```
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this into the `HTML` page's `<head>`, because `firebaseui.js` defines the missing `firebaseui`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.css" />
```

This must be loaded before the `app.js` is being loaded, so the it won't be undefined anymore.